# How to do Datarow[] Groupby and orderby resultset in Datarow[]

Tags: c#

I would like to do something like this in .NET 3.5. What's the quickest way?

```
IEnumerable<DataRow[]> list =
                (from r in datarow.AsEnumerable()
                 group r by r[CoumnName]).
                 SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(r => r[CoumnName]));

Datarow[]  resultDatarow = list.Cast<Datarow[]>;
```

How to do this?

Comment: looks like that is the only you do with `LINQ`, there is no more way.

Comment: Why don't do groupby and orderby in database query?

Comment: @Chris Groupby and Orederby is on Demand so do not do in SQL Query

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the `ToArray` and don't use `SelectMany`:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow[]> list = (from r in datarow.AsEnumerable()
                               group r by r[CoumnName]).
                               Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r[CoumnName]).ToArray());
Datarow[][]  resultDatarow = list.ToArray();
```